# Getting error when I want to instantiate my chainCode

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-chaincode

I get the following error when I want to instantiate my chaincode 
Error: could not assemble transaction, err proposal response was not successful, error code 500, msg chaincode registration failed: container exited with 254

I checked docker container logs and I found this. ERRO 03c [mychannel][28f17b3d] failed to invoke chaincode name:"lscc" , error: container exited with 254
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode.(*RuntimeLauncher).Launch.func1
/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/runtime_launcher.go:63
runtime.goexit
/opt/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1333
chaincode registration failed

Comment: Can you tell more about the environment setup?like the versions of ubuntu,docker,go,node?plus can you add a snap of your peer-base.yaml file?

Answer (score 0):

Chaincode instantiation can be failed due to multiple reasons and here it seems that the it is not able to invoke the lifecycle system chaincode because either you have not specified the correct path to the chaincode or the peer on which chaincode is installed is not accessible. Also make sure that your chaincode is installed on the peer using which you are instantiating your chaincode.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I put my chaincode in the chaincode folder of fabric-sample, so I supposed it should be able to automatically recognize my chaincode based on volume defined in docker -compose.yml in the basic network. My chaincode passes installation part successfully so I think it should have access to the path of my chaincode. I didn't change the network configuration and docker -compose.yml at all. I just changed fabcar bashfile to start my network and install and instantiate my javascript chaincode instead of fabcar chaincode.

Comment: Try using this environment variable then CORE_PEER_CHAINCODELISTENADDRESS = 0.0.0.0:7051 in the dockercompose file.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by removing the docker images using `docker rmi $(docker images dev-* -q)`. At first, I only killed my docker containers before each new setup and it is not enough. I used these three commands to kill docker containers and remove images.

```
docker kill $(docker ps -q)
docker rm $(docker ps -aq)
docker rmi $(docker images "dev-*" -q)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the first error appeared in the console.
for me it was like that:

`Local fabric-ca binaries and docker images are out of sync. This may cause problems`

then I figured out that I am using the bin and configs of older versions of hlf I went to [download binaries and images from here](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#download-fabric-samples-docker-images-and-binaries) and installed latest version of fabric samples and got the latest **bin** and **config** files from there